# Where to see PHP error log if no access to /var/log/apache

Tags: php, access-denied, error-log

My web host is running ubuntu 10.04 for our web server.  I am trying to see my PHP error output that I usually would see in `/var/log/apache2/error_log...` but I have no access to `/var/log/apache2/`.  I am getting an HTML 500 error, and usually I would check the PHP error log.  Does anyone know how to check the log without having to access `/var/log/apache2/`?

Thanks!

Comment: So your question is how to access something you don't have access to?

Comment: Do you have shell access at all?

Comment: @mensi +1 Yes I have shell access.  I am using the master user account  for our subscription to our web host.  I have access to a folder in `/home/our_username/`.  I make files in there, which has our public web folder.  No access to `/var/log/apache2/` and I need to check the php error log.

Comment: can you execute the php code from the console? like: $ php index.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the error log to somewhere else where you can access it, using the function ini_set in your php script e.g.,

ini_set('error_log','/home/username/error.log');

Comment: For future users, you might also have to turn on error logging all together:

    `ini_set('log_errors', true);`
    `ini_set('error_log', $root . 'error.log');`